# Use constructor parameters outside constructor in constexpr class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, constexpr

I am trying to implement matrix-like class, using an std::array to actually store the data. All of the data is known at compile-time.

I want to be able to use initializer-lists to initialize the Matrix. Something along the lines of

```
Matrix m = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

I also want to be able to set the dimensions of my matrix during instantiation.

My current code is similar to the following:

```
template<int m, int n>
class Matrix {
public:

    using initializer_list2d = std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<float> >;
    using array2d = std::array< std::array<float, m>, n >;

    consteval Matrix(initializer_list2d initList) {
        // static_assert to check initList length [...]

        int i = 0;
        for (auto &row : initList) {
            // static_assert to check row length [...]

            std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), data_[i].begin());
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Definitions of operators and methods [...]
private:
    array2d data_;
};
```

In order to use this though, I have to set the dimensions through the template:

```
Matrix<3, 3> m = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

It seems to me, that since the constructor is consteval (and all of its parameters have to be known at compile-time anyway) it should somehow bet possible to deduce the dimensions through the initializer-list alone.

Using a dynamic data type (e.g. vector) is not possible for my application, since this program has to be able to run without access to the heap.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your constructor's parameters don't have to be known at compile-time. Even if they did (via `consteval`), you would have to deal with [constant evaluation happening after template instantiation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0992r0.pdf).

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the fact that 'constexpr' is really more of a suggestion to the compiler, if this is what you mean. I will reformulate part of my question.

Comment: What I should say to not misquote that paper is that constant evaluation is separate rather than happening after. Regardless of when an evaluation happens (the constructor call in this case), it can't instantiate templates during that process. I don't see a technical reason a counterpart to `initializer_list` couldn't exist that still makes the constructor a list constructor, but also provides the size as a template argument because the compiler definitely knows how large it is. I'm not sure how to do it otherwise without compromising in some way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! I will try to find a solution with the new information you have given me, otherwise I may just have to live with the templated class

Comment: @zomnombom Please see the edited answer. It's been simplified a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++17 there is no deduction of template arguments for a class template, so this is not possible.

From C++17, you can write this deduction guide:

```
template<int m, int n>
Matrix(float const (&)[n][m]) -> Matrix<m, n>;
```

and add an extra pair of braces when constructing the `Matrix`:

```
Matrix m = 
{
 {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6},
  {7, 8, 9}
 }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tco3bq).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that works for raw arrays when it doesn't for `std::array`. Pre-C++17, you can use a traditional `make_` function, it just means that you need an extra `()` around the braces. ([Quick example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Enchjx))

Comment: @chris Yeah, an extra factory function would certainly work. I think OP specifically wants argument deduction directly though. And `std::array` will deduce the size from C++17 as well.

Comment: I didn't go beyond testing it on GCC and Clang, but neither [accept this test](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Keda8P) (and no deduction guide needed if that constructor takes a raw `const int(&)[N]`). Seems a raw array is the only way to get the type deduction to trigger properly from the braces, and I wish I'd known that would work before. In that case, the raw array is the templated counterpart to `initializer_list` that I was going on about above since `std::array` doesn't do the job.

Comment: @chris Just because a `std::array` can deduce the size doesn't mean that `S` can. Are you expecting it to use the constructor to deduce the size? You still need to provide a deduction guide, and then it [works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dedasf).

Comment: I was expecting the compiler would deduce `N` in the constructor's parameter (which it can do with `S` out of the picture) and match that to the `N` on `S` itself without needing a raw-array guide on `S`. I certainly have room to learn when it comes to what exactly CTAD offers implicitly. It's worth noting that no guide is needed if the constructor itself takes the raw array ref.

Comment: @chris Ah, I see. Look up "non-deduced contexts" to understand part of the issue with that. Also, even more has changed in C++20, so in certain contexts CTAD will work where in C++17 a deduction guide is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another interesting solution, using variadic templates:

```
template<int m, class T, class... U>
struct Matrix {
    Matrix(const T (&t)[m], const U (& ...u)[m]) {
        std::copy(t, t+m, arr[0]);

        int i = 0;
        (std::copy(u, u+m, arr[++i]), ...);
    }   

    T (arr[m])[sizeof...(U) + 1]; 
};
```

It even allows for getting rid of the second brace required in cigien's answer and doesn't need a template deduction guide (Although it still needs C++17 in order for `int m` to be automatically deduced):

```
Matrix mat = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

Also, the compiler seems to be able to optimze this quite a bit, as seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fhz9Kq)